# Can't find variable in the current scope?

Tags: ruby, erb

When trying to add tracing output to an ERB template I hit the following issue when trying to find where variable `ex_title` comes from.

Tried to list all possible variables in the current scope, but there
simply does not exist:

```
<%= instance_variables.grep(/ex_title/) %>  # renders an empty array
<%= global_variables.grep(/ex_title/) %>    # renders an empty array
<%= local_variables.grep(/ex_title/) %>     # renders an empty array

<%= instance_variables.sort %>   # renders array with many elements
<%= global_variables.sort %>     # renders array with many elements
<%= local_variables.sort %>      # renders array with many elements
```

Whereas `ex_title` variable provably does exist:

```
<%= ex_title %>                  # renders "Categories - Online store"
<%= ex_title.class %>            # renders "String"
<%= ex_title.object_id %>        # renders "15825900"
```

Where else can be found if not in global, local or instance variables?

Comment: Maybe it is a helper function returning a string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Then you must conclude that it is a method. Use [`defined?`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/docs/ProgrammingRuby/tut_expressions.html#definedandorandnot) to determine what `ex_title` is. For example:

```
defined? ex_title  #=> nil

def ex_title; end
defined? ex_title  #=> "method"

ex_title = Object.new
defined? ex_title  #=> "local-variable"
```

Comment: thanks. defined? did helped to reveal it is a method in the end.